# How to check if a variable is passed to a function with or without quotes?

Tags: r, function, dataframe

I'm trying to write a R function that can take either quoted or unquoted data frame variable name or vector of variable names as a parameter. The problem is when the user inserts **unquoted dataframe column names** as function input parameters it **results in** "object not found" **error**. How can I check if the variable name is quoted?

I've tried exists(), missing(), substitute() but none of them works for all combinations.

```
# considering this printfun as something I can't change 
#made it just for demosnstration purposeses
printfun <- function(df, ...){
  for(item in list(...)){
    print(df[item])
  }

}
```

```
myfun<-function(df,x){

  #should check if input is quoted or unquoted here 

  # substitute works for some cases not all (see below)
  new_args<-c(substitute(df),substitute(x))
  do.call(printfun,new_args)

}
```

```
#sample data
df<-data.frame(abc=1,dfg=2)

#these are working
myfun(df,c("abc")) 
myfun(df,c("abc","dfg"))
myfun(df,"abc")

#these are failing with object not found
myfun(df,abc)
myfun(df,c(abc))
```

I can differentiate the `myfun(df,abc)` and `myfun(df,"abc")` with a try Catch block. Although this does not seem very neat.

But I haven't found any way to differentiate the second argument in `myfun(df,c(abc))` from `myfun(df,abc)` ?

Alternatively, can I somehow check if the error comes from missing quotes, as I guess the object not found error might arise also from something else (eg the dataframe name) being mistyped?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This appears to work for all your cases:

```r
myfun<-function(df,x){

  sx <- substitute(x)
  a <- tryCatch(is.character(x), error = function(e) FALSE)
  if (a) {
      new_x <- x
  } else {
      cx <- as.character(sx)
      if (is.name(sx)) {
          new_x <- cx
      } else if (is.call(sx) && cx[1] == "c") {
          new_x <- cx[-1]
      } else {
          stop("Invalid x")
      }
  }
  new_args <- c(substitute(df), as.list(new_x))
  do.call(printfun, new_args)
}
```

However, I feel there is something strange about what you are trying to do.

Comment: Thank you! Checking if it  `is.call` was what I was missing! Why do you think it's strange? I'm not that familiar with R but from my experience users are quite confused when they need to enter quoted and when unquoted column names to functions. e.g  `aes` in ggplot2 takes only unquoted while `aes_string` is for quoted  datafame column names